# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
 This is the errror, tried a few things but still to no avail.
```

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object referenc**e                                                                        at com.dllibrary.cart.SigninMainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(***SigninMainActivity.java:56)***
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

**code for my sign in method**

```
     signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           final ProgressDialog mdialog = new       ProgressDialog(SigninMainActivity.this);
            mdialog.setMessage("Please waiting");
            mdialog.show();
            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //check if user not exist
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(phone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                        //Get User Information
                        mdialog.dismiss();

                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(phone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                       if (user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString())) {
                            Intent homeIntent= new Intent(SigninMainActivity.this, home.class);
                            Common.currentUser = user;
                            startActivity(homeIntent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(SigninMainActivity.this, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }else{
                        mdialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SigninMainActivity.this, "User Does Not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

**line 56 is at "if(user.getPassword.equals)"**

Comment: Try to use

if ( user.getPassword() != null && password.getText() != null && user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString()))

instead of
 if (user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString()))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44873766/null-pointer-exception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-void?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, Prathibha, it worked okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code I implement with the change I expected.

```
    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               final ProgressDialog mdialog = new       ProgressDialog(SigninMainActivity.this);
                mdialog.setMessage("Please waiting");
                mdialog.show();
                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //check if user not exist
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(phone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                            //Get User Information
                            mdialog.dismiss();

                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(phone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
//Check the null
                           if (user.getPassword() != null && password.getText() != null && user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString())) {
                                Intent homeIntent= new Intent(SigninMainActivity.this, home.class);
                                Common.currentUser = user;
                                startActivity(homeIntent);
                                finish();
                            } else {

                                Toast.makeText(SigninMainActivity.this, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }else{
                            mdialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SigninMainActivity.this, "User Does Not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Tells you what is all about. It means that in this line of code:

```
if (user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString()))
```

That exists at line `56`, `user.getPassword()` returns `null`.

This is happening because the `User` object that you are trying to get from the database has the value of `null`. So to solve this, make sure you get the correct `User` object. Also, check this object for nullity before actually using it:

```
if(user != null) {}
```

Comment: Good point @alex, thanks for the precise explanation, on how i can approach the process once more.